# Add legend to a riverplot

Tags: r, plot, legend, sankey-diagram

I've been having fun playing around with the *riverplot* package, as in the below example.

Is there a way to add a legend to a riverplot, showing what the colors correspond to? I'm imagining something below the plot with blocks of colors and text saying what those colors are.

```
library(riverplot)


river <- riverplot.example()
test <- plot(river,plot_area=0.9)
```

Comment: Did you try `legend()`? Try: `legend(0, 1, c("A", "B"))`.

Comment: z8754 - do I then manually add the colors? Do you know how that is done?

Comment: I don't think it needs a legend, as the text is already on the plot, defining each colour. For example "H" is red, "A" is green, etc.

Comment: Yes, we would need to assign colours manually if we intend to use legend, something like: `legend("bottomright", legend = c("A", "H"), fill = c("red", "green"))`

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/13936223/680068